# Change bool in initState flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page with this code:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

bool isFirstLoading = true;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (isFirstLoading) {
      getInfo();
      setState(() {
        isFirstLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      getInfoFromSharedPref();
    }
  }

Future<http.Response> getInfo() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Loader.show(context,
        isAppbarOverlay: true,
        isBottomBarOverlay: true,
        progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator());
    var url = kLinkAPI + "/getInfo";

    var response =
        await http.post(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});

    var resObj = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (response != null) {
      setState(() {
        if (resObj.length > 0) {
          address = resObj[0]['address'];
          countryInfo = resObj[0]['country_info'];
          phone = resObj[0]['phone'];
          latitude = resObj[0]['latitude'];
          longitude = resObj[0]['longitude'];
          isFirstLoading = false;

          prefs.setString('address', address);
          prefs.setString('countryInfo', countryInfo);
          prefs.setString('phone', phone);
          prefs.setString('latitude', latitude);
          prefs.setString('longitude', longitude);
        }
      });
    }
    Loader.hide();
  }

void getInfoFromSharedPref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      address = prefs.getString('address');
      countryInfo = prefs.getString('countryInfo');
      phone = prefs.getString('phone');
      latitude = prefs.getString('latitude');
      longitude = prefs.getString('longitude');
    });
  }

}
```

I would like to make sure that the first time I enter the page, the **isFirstLoading** variable is set to false and then calls the getInfo function with the http call while if it is false it takes from the shared preferences.

**isFirstLoading** is now always true

how could I solve?

Comment: Can you help me understand better? You want `isFirstLoading` to be false whenever this widget is created. After that, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The first time you enter this page, make an http call to a service, while from the second time onwards, take the data from the shared preferences

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating your code. Let me know if this solves your issue.:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  SharedPreferences  prefs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getInfo();
  }
  

  // ...
}
```

Now, the first time this widget is inserted into the tree:

1. `initState()` will be called once.
2. Therefore, `getInfo()` will be called. `getInfo()` will make the http call and update the `prefs` variable using `setState`, which you have already done.
3. Whenever the widget is reloaded, the `prefs` variable will not be lost since it is a stateful widget.

---

Next, if you would like to save the preference settings locally instead of making an http call every time the user opens the app, you should handle that inside of `getInfo()` itself. Something like this:

```
  getInfo() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getBool("isFirstLoading") == false) {
      // setState to update prefs variable
    } else {
      // make http call
      // save prefs (optional)
      // setState to update prefs variable
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand correctly, you are trying to only call the `getInfo` method on the first load, and the `getInfoFromSharedPref` all the other time.

My suggestion is to save the `isFirstLoading` bool as a preference like so:

```dart
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool isFirstLoading = prefs.getBool("isFirstLoading") ?? true;

  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();

    if (isFirstLoading) {
      await getInfo();
      await prefs.setBool("isFirstLoading", false);
      isFirstLoading = false;
    } else {
      getInfoFromSharedPref();
    }
  }

  Future<http.Response> getInfo() async {
    // …
  }

  void getInfoFromSharedPref() async {
    // …
  }
}
```

Comment: Not can add await in _HomeScreenState without async?

Comment: @joisberg No, usually you always need an asynchronous scope (async) to have await.